# SQL query to compare column of geohashes with an unspecified number of short keys?

Tags: sql, geohashing

I've got a table with a column of long geohash keys.  My goal is to write a (Snowflake) SQL query to select those rows that match a set of bounding boxes. For the corner of each bounding box I have computed a short geohash (length dictated by the size of the bounding box).

I've deduplicated those bounding box geohash keys to improve efficiency. As a result there are no longer strictly 4 keys associated with each bounding box.

The goal would be a query that generates a table like the one below. The **geohash** and **corner_keys** columns are inputs and the **within** column is the output.

The **corner_keys** column is a **list(varchar)** datatype that I wish existed but probably doesn't.

| geohash | corner_keys | within |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9rv4a0nnq8 | 9rv,c4u | TRUE |
| c4x99uq10x | 9rv,c4u | FALSE |
| 9rv4a0nnq8 | 9rx,9rq,9rm,9rv | TRUE |
| c4x99uq10x | c4x | TRUE |

The SQL would look something like

```
any(startswith(geohash, corner_keys)) as within
```

How does one compare a geohash to a unspecified number of short keys?

Comment: Please update your  question with with your table ddl, some sample data and the result you want to achieve from that data

Comment: @NickW Thank you for the suggestion. I've added an example table and pseudocode.